# Checking and Saving/Loading from MySQL C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am making something that requires MySQL. I have the saving done from in-game, which is simply done by INSERT.

I have a column that will have a password in and I need to check if the inputted password matched any of the rows and then if it is, get all of the contents of the row then save it to variables.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this in C#?

//////////////////////////

I have found how to save and get the string, however it will only get 1 string at a time :(

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM (player) WHERE (pass)";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
ayy = reader.GetString(1);
print (ayy);
if(ayy == password){
    //something
}
```

Comment: I can't quite remember the SQL for it as it's been a few months since I last used it (and thus will not post as an answer), but you should be able to query for a row with an entry in the Password column matching the password entered. It would then, I assume, hand back either an object or a string which you could handle appropriately (e.g. using regular expressions). You'll want to be careful, however, if the passwords are not unique as you may end up with multiple rows returning to your program.

Comment: Hi Cragor, I am making sure the user input a unique password :)

Comment: It's only getting one string at a time in the sense of only getting one column's worth of information at a time? If not, what are you seeing? What strings does the reader contain?

Comment: //ALL WRONG nevermind, was getting that wrong :/

Comment: The reader contains pass (first row), changing the int in GetString  changes the column so 2 would be name etc, I need to to only view the pass column and check them all :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My best practice is to use `MySQLDataAdapter` to fill a `DataTable`. You can then iterate through the rows and try to match the password.

Something like this;

```
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      using(MySQLDataAdapter adapter = new MySQLDataAdaper(query, connection))
      { 
            adapter.Fill(dt);
      }

      foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      {
         //Supposing you stored your password in a stringfield in your database
        if((row.Field<String>("columnName").Equals("password"))
        {
               //Do something with it
        }


      }
```

I hope this compiles since I typed this from my phone. You can find a nice explanation and example [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldataadapter.html).

However, if you are needing data from a specific user, why not specificly ask it from the database? Your query would be like;

```
      SELECT * FROM usercolumn WHERE user_id = input_id AND pass = input_pass
```

Since I suppose every user is unique, you will now get the data from the specific user, meaning you should not have to check for passwords anymore.

Comment: Would "tableName" be my table that I have my password column in? Also getting error : foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type `System.Data.DataTable' because it does not contain a definition for `GetEnumerator' or is not accessible

Comment: You would have to be iterating through the rows or columns, not the table itself.

Comment: I edited it to "columnName" to make it more clear. The error you get is probably because I forgot to tell the foreach loop to iterate over `dt.Rows` instead of `dt`. The code should now work.

Comment: Also getting 'The member `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand' cannot be used as method or delegate'

Comment: @Cragor true, mentioned it right after I posted it.

Comment: @user2913720 you can also pass the query and the connection to the `MySQLDataAdapter` when you create the instance. Check the code again.

Comment: Hi Dion, it fixed the other error but I still have: 'Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `object'' on the if(((string) line.

Comment: Well, it seems I should practice my coding skills without compiling a bit more. The `[0]` should not be there. You should be able to typecast it to a `string` though, I'm quite sure on that one. My apologies for the troubles.

Answer (score -1):

For the SQL statement, you should be able to search your database as follows and get only the entry you need back from it.

```
"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE input_string"
```

If `input_string` contains any of the special characters for SQL string comparison (% and _, I believe) you'll just have to escape them which can be done quite simply with regex. As I said in the comments, it's been a while since I've done SQL, but there's plenty of resources online for perfecting that query.

This should then return the entire row, and if I'm thinking correctly you should be able to then put the entire row into an array of objects all at once, or simply read them string by string and convert to values as needed using one of the `Convert` methods, as found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx

**Edit as per Prix's comment:** Data entered into the MySQL table should not need conversion.

Example to get an integer:

```
string x = [...];
[...]
var y = Convert.ToInt32(x);
```

If you're able to get them into object arrays, that works as well.

```
object[] obj = [...];
[...]
var x0 = Convert.To[...](obj[0]);
var x1 = Convert.To[...](obj[1]);
```

Etcetera.

Comment: You don't have to convert anything if you properly used the methods available with MySql.Data to read the data.

Comment: Fair enough. Been a while as I said. I'll make a mention of that. Thanks!

Comment: [Public Instance Methods](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommandmembers.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommand-executereader-overloads) which shows [GetInt32](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommandmembers.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqldatareader-getint32) and several others.

Comment: Interesting. Might have to look into that link a bit more myself for an upcoming project. My previous experience with C#/MySQL came from elsewhere, so some of the specifics are unknown to me. Thanks again.